# How To Compare Items In Two Lists Python 3.3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, comparison

I tried using `cmp(list1, list2)` to learn it's no longer supported in Python 3.3. I've tried many other complex approaches, but none have worked.

I have two lists of which both contain just words and I want it to check to see how many words feature in both and return the number for how many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the length of the set intersection using `&` like this:

```
len(set(list1) & set(list2))
```

**Example:**

```
>>>len(set(['cat','dog','pup']) & set(['rat','cat','wolf']))
1
>>>set(['cat','dog','pup']) & set(['rat','cat','wolf'])
{'cat'}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use sets for some reason, you can always use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which supports most multiset operations:

```
>>> from collections import Counter 
>>> print(list((Counter(['cat','dog','wolf']) & Counter(['pig','fish','cat'])).elements()))
['cat']
```

Comment: I keep getting 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'' :/

Comment: @SirBuncey what exactly is your current attempted code?

Comment: Ah! I've fixed it. I've started using tuples now thanks.

Comment: @SirBuncey I'm glad you solved your problem, but do note there is no error with doing it the way I outlined :)

Comment: It's just my poor coding then ;)

Comment: @SirBuncey I'm not trying to put your coding into question, I'm just affirming that I have run everything I placed in my answer and it does work!  You are definitely using Python-3.x and just copied my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the count of how many words are common

```
common = sum(1 for i in list1 if i in list2)
```

If you actually want to get a list of the shared words

```
common_words = set(list1).intersection(list2)
```