# How can I find a match in 2 separate python lists?

Tags: python-3.7

list1 = [a, b, c, d]
list2 = [b, e, f, g]

How can I compare list 1 and 2 and find the match (b)?

Comment: This question has already been answered in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210210/how-to-compare-items-in-two-lists-python-3-3

Comment: `set(list1) & set(list2)`, though @Tijani is correct that this is a duplicate.